# How to update ImageView (images) after a delay without freezing UI and allowing user clicks?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, imageview

In MainActivity.java there is an array of ImageView.
The idea was to change images after a condition and after a delay of 1200ms.
When clicking on images and meanwhile the delay is running in a seperate thread,
the update of which images to change was changed in unexpected way, guess it because of wrong
use of threads in Andorid.

Trying to do a simple memory game in Andorid.
In case two different cards were selected, wish to display the "back" after a delay and not the "front" of those cards.

As example: if 3 cards were clicked at the time of a delay, 
updated wrong cards. e.g. cards: 0,1,2 were clicked in a short time.
0 and 1 images expected to be changed. But images 1,2 were actually changed.

Trying to check values- it looks that outside the thread with a delay -
Updated with the expected values. Inside the thread it didn't.

In MainActivity.java -

```
 public void hidecards() {
         Handler ha = new Handler();
         Runnable rn = new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                  ivcardsarr[clicked_cards[0]].setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
                  ivcardsarr[clicked_cards[1]].setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
             }
         }; ha.postDelayed(rn, 1200);
}
```

This method is calling by it's name (hidecards()).

I have tried to changed it to delay or something else, all with the same result.

Any idea please what it the correct way to work with threads using this case?
Thank you.

Comment: More info please... is this throwing an exception? or is it just freezing the ui during the1200 ms delay?

Comment: It just updated (changed) wrong images. No exception. As example: There is an array of 16 images (16 "cards"). Clicking on two different ImageViews should change those two images after a delay of 1200ms. This is working well. The problem starts when clicking in a short time on more than 2 images, e.g. 3. This will change after the delay the last 2 clicked images, and not the first 2 clicked images as expected. Without a delay or without doing it within a thread+delay it works. Adding int to keep values inside the thread also updated well.

Comment: This means that clicking on images 0 , 1 , 2 . Images: 1,2 changed and not images 0,1. Out of the thread the array of clicked_cards (-which is an array of int, represent location of image Ids in array that represents imageviews 'ivcardsarr) it updates with 0,1. But inside the thread/run() its updated with 1,2 when clicking on cards while the delay/this thread is running.

Comment: *Probably something wrong with the way I have implemented the delay/thread. My guess It updates out of the main ("UI" thread) in case clicking (selecting another "imageview") at the same time of the delay. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are updating the array clicked_cards in between the time the postDelayed is called and the runnable's run method is executed. You should pass the array to the hideCards method as a variable so it becomes local to that method.

Comment: Thanks, "clicked_cards" is a global array, but anyway, Tried to do so, : void hidecards(int a, int b) , but there are error inside run()  e.g.:"Variable 'a' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declare final".

                void hidecards(int a, int b) 
  Handler h = new Handler();
         Runnable r = new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 ivcardsarr[a].setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
                 ivcardsarr[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
    }
         }; h.postDelayed(r, 1200);
}

Comment: correct, local variables must be declared final to be used in an inner class. check answer posted

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void hidecards(final ImageView cardOne, final ImageView cardTwo) {
         Handler ha = new Handler();
         Runnable rn = new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                  cardOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
                  cardTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
             }
         }; 
         ha.postDelayed(rn, 1200);
}
```

Call this through the following:

```
hideCards(ivcardsarr[clicked_cards[0]], ivcardsarr[clicked_cards[1]]);
```

**Why use local variables:**

When you passed the array as a field you essentially passed it a reference to the intended object instead of the object itself. so when you clicked on the next card you updated the reference. By the time the runnable was called you had already told it to look at a different object, so the new object was updated instead. By passing it the actual object instead it is given a reference that isn't changed when you click a new card.

**Why java insists on using final variable in inner classes**

This is essentially to the reference doesn't get confused. In the end it doesn't end up making a huge difference since you aren't planning on redefining the variable anyways. You can get around this by building a sub class which includes getters and setters or using global variables.

Comment: Thank you. This way it works. It also worked when I did something like this - hidecards() {
final int swap1 = clicked_cards[0];
final int swap2 = clicked_cards[1];

public void run() {
ivcardsarr[swap1].setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
ivcardsarr[swap2].setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
}
}
I have seen in your prev. comment why the final was required. Thank you so much!

Comment: "Runnable" is an inner class. Thank you for the great explenation!